# Upload image Spring boot

Tags: java, spring

I have Spring Boot code with image upload as follows. Can anyone tell me how to not save the book when I don't upload pictures when I press save?

Here is code in controller

```
@PostMapping("/books") 
public String saveBook(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book, Model model, BindingResult bindingResult, @RequestParam(value = "image") MultipartFile image) throws IOException { bookValidator.validate(book, bindingResult); 
 model.addAttribute("categories", bookCategoryService.findAll());
    model.addAttribute("mode", "create");

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "create_book";
    }

    String fileName = null;
    if(image.getOriginalFilename() != null) {
        fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(image.getOriginalFilename());
        book.setPhotos(fileName);
    }

    Book savedBook = bookService.saveBook(book);
    String uploadDir = "book-photos/" + savedBook.getId();

    if(fileName != null) {
        FileUploadUtil.saveFile(uploadDir, fileName, image);
    }

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

This is code in FileUploadUtil

```
package com.example.bookmanagement.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public class FileUploadUtil {
    public static void saveFile(String uploadDir, String fileName, MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
        Path uploadPath = Paths.get(uploadDir);

        if (!Files.exists(uploadPath)) {
            Files.createDirectories(uploadPath);
        }

        try (InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream()) {
            Path filePath = uploadPath.resolve(fileName);
            Files.copy(inputStream, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new IOException("Could not save image file: " + fileName, ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is picture located ? in book model ? then, you have to check is picture exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can add validation while you are saving image details in `saveBook` business method ::

```
    String fileName = null;
    if (image != null && image.getOriginalFileName() != null) {
       fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(image.getOriginalFilename());
       book.setPhotos(fileName);

       Book savedBook = bookService.saveBook(book);
       String uploadDir = "book-photos/" + savedBook.getId();

       FileUploadUtil.saveFile(uploadDir, fileName, image);
   }
```

Just ignore the `save` snippet when you are not uploading pictures.